# Git-Flow (with Sourcetree client) and VSTS

Tags: git, azure-devops

I switched from SVN to git some time ago and currently I am using git with VSTS. Until now I had worked only with master and feature branches. VSTS is setup with branch policies. Master changes/commits are only possible via Pull-Requests.

Now I tried to use git-flow. I have configured the develop branch to also use branch-policies in vsts.

If I create a feature-branch I can push it to vsts.

But I can't finish the feature locally using git-flow because it would merge into develop (which I can not push to vsts because of the branch policy). 
If I complete the pull-request it will be merged by vsts into develop. I can pull this change back to my local repo but the git-flow-feature-task will remain "open". I can not finish it, because it will merge locally.

Currently I am using squash commits with the pull request and after it I am deleting the "unfinished" local feature branch.

I don't like this approach but I can not figure out how to manage it correctly

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're doing things right (push feature_branch, merge future_branch via a pull request, pull `develop`, ...start over on another feature...).

When you complete the pull request there is an option to complete the linked work items after merging.

[image]

Comment: thanks, I know this. Sorry, I did not explain correctly. I thought about the local repositories feature branch. I am using Sourcetree. Normaly I would click on "git-flow" to finish the feature. But this would result in a local merge to develop which would infact diverge the local develop from the origin develop. I hope this explanation is understandable?

Comment: The title should then be git flow and SourceTree

Comment: I changed the title